# How to write Item writer to save DB

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-batch

How to write Item writer to save DB.

I am using spring batch where I am able to create a custom IteamReader. Now I need to save to DB but i am not getting hold of data in Item Writer.

here is my code  :

```
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    MyRepo myrepo;
    
    @Bean
    public ItemReader<MyDTO> itemReader() {
        return new myItemReader();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<MyDTO> itemWriter() {
        return new LoggingItemWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step exampleJobStep(ItemReader<MyDTO> reader,
                               ItemWriter<MyDTO> writer,
                               StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("exampleJobStep")
                .<MyDTO, MyDTO>chunk(1)
                .reader(reader)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job exampleJob(Step exampleJobStep,
                          JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("exampleJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(exampleJobStep)
                .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Now I will show you itemreader and itemWriter code.

ITEMREADER :

```
public class myItemReader implements ItemReader<MyDTO> {
 
    private int index;
    private List<MyDTO> myData = new ArrayList<>();
 
    InMemoryStudentReader() {
        initialize();
    }
 
    private void initialize() {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            MyDTO newObj = new MyDTO();
            newObj.setId(id) 
            newObj.setName(firstName);
            // some random setting values based on index...

            myData.add(newObj);
            index = 0;
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    public MyDTO read() throws Exception {
        MyDTO nextDTO = null;
 
        if (index < myData.size()) {
            nextDTO = myData.get(index);
            index++;
        }
        else {
            index = 0;
        }
 
        return nextDTO;
    }
}
```

ItemWriter ;

```
public class LoggingItemWriter implements ItemWriter<AreaBoundaryDTO>{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingItemWriter.class);

    public LoggingItemWriter() {
       System.out.println("test");

    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends AreaBoundaryDTO> list) throws Exception {
        for (MyDTO item : list) {
            System.out.println("test"+list);
        }

    }
}
```

What I want here is I want to save Data in myrepo.save() where data is myArray list which i have saved in myData during Iteamreader.

Can anybody help me how to save these data which I am getting in itemreader to database through JPA repository.

I was following this [Example](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-creating-a-custom-itemreader/)

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared is incorrect: The reader is defined as `ItemReader<StudentDTO>` but the read method returns another type `public MyDTO read()`.

Spring Batch provides the `RepositoryItemWriter` which uses a JPA repository to persist items in a database. If needed, you can extend this built-in writer to customize how data is persisted.

Comment: oops !! that was typo mistake as i was changing data for SOF. Well so my question was is my itemreader correct ? and if yes then where i should read `myData` so I can do write operation for saving in DB.

Comment: I can't answer that question because I don't know your requirement and your domain model relations and constraints.

Comment: I need to save `myData` to `myRepo`.

Comment: According to your code, `myData` is a list as a field in your item reader implementation. The reader will return items from that list, and those items will be handed to the item writer. So using the `RepositoryItemWriter` will save those items to the DB. So you just need to replace the `LoggingItemWriter` with A `RepositoryItemWriter< MyDTO>` in your step.

Comment: I need to replace in Batch config file ?